# How to use both react-apollo and react-router-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to add react-router-native to my react-native/react-apollo application but when the `<Query>` tag gets the data back to the client the component doesn't render again (always show the `<Loading/>` tag). Am I doing it wrong?

**App.js**

```html
...

render() {
  const { isLoggedIn, token, hp } = this.state;
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Login onLogin={this.handleLogin} />;
  } else {
    return (
      <NativeRouter>
        <ApolloProvider client={CreateApolloClient(token)}>
          <Switch>
           <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
          </Switch>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </NativeRouter>
    );
  }
}

...
```

---

**Home.js**

```html
...

<Query query={getHomeData}>
 {({ loading, error, data: { getHomeData: data } }) => {
   return loading ? ( <Loading /> ) : (
      <ScrollView style={style.dataContainer}>
         <Text>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }}
</Query>

...
```

---

**Loading.js**

```html
...

return (
  <View>
    <Text>LOADING CONTENT...</Text>
  </View>
);

...
```

Comment: Could you post a small reproduction on https://codesandbox.io?